# Show that $\sqrt{\det J^T J}$ is equal to the 2-norm of the $\binom{m}{n}$ square sub-determinants of $J\in{\bf R}^{m\times n}.$

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-forms, jacobian, change-of-variable

> Show that $\sqrt{\det J^T J}$ is equal to the 2-norm of the
>   $\binom{m}{n}$ square sub-determinants of  $J\in{\bf R}^{m\times n}.$

This is something I came across after a considerable amount of grief trying to figure out how to do a change of variables for the integration of an $n$ dimensional solid embedded in ${\bf R}^m$.

Basically, every introductory vector calculus book talks about how we have

$$\int_VdV=\int_W|\det J_F(x)|dx_1\ldots dx_m,$$

when $F:W\subseteq{\bf R}^m\to{\bf R}^m$.

However when $F:W\subseteq{\bf R}^n\to{\bf R}^m$ for $n<m$, then it's not obvious what to do since the Jacobian is no longer square.  After a lot of reflection and experimentation, I realized that the appropriate generalization is this:

$$\int_VdV=\int_W\sqrt{\det(J_F(x)^TJ_F(x))}dx_1\ldots dx_n.$$

Believe it or not, this generalization is not mentioned on the Wikipedia pages for the Jacobian, or for the CoV for Integration.

As it happens, $\sqrt{\det J^T J}$ has another, more geometric, interpretation, being equal to the 2-norm of the $\binom{m}{n}$ square sub-determinants of  $J\in{\bf R}^{m\times n}.$

A proof of this fact would probably be enlightening, but I'm also interested in how this relates to differential forms, as I'm pretty sure differential forms are just an abstraction/algebraification of this equality.

Comment: Is $J$ any matrix ?

Comment: @JeanMarie $J$ is any matrix in ${\bf R}^{m \times n}$.

Comment: See (arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0062)

Comment: @JeanMarie Interesting! I'll check this out.

Comment: It's a consequence of the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula).

Comment: I'm also interested in doing a change of variables like you describe. The formula you give relating the volumes appears to be called the smooth coarea formula in the literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer given in the comments, this is a consequence of the Cauchy-Binet Formula.